# Choose $h$ and $k$ such that the system has, no solution, a unique solution, and many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking through my textbook, I see no examples as to how to solve this

\begin{align}
x - 3y  & = 1  \\
2x + hy & = k
\end{align}

Comment: Well think about it. The only way the two would have no solution is if they are parallel (and not coincident). For a unique solution, they should not be parallel. And to have many solutions, they should be coincident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $h \neq -6$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$: unique solution, $x = (h+3k)/(h+6), y = (k-2)/(h+6) $
- $h =  -6$, $k = 2$: infinitely many solutions, $ x = 3t + 1, y = t, \ t \in \mathbb{R} $
- $h =  -6$, $k \neq 2$: no solution.

> ***If you show us what your thinkings are on this problem I will gladly elaborate some more on my answer.***

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to choose h so that the two lhs are essentially the same. Then you by picking suitable k you can get a contradiction or two essentially identical equations (giving respectively no, many solutions). Other h should give a unique solution.